# Not able to set System property in spark application [In client and cluster mode]

Tags: java, apache-spark

To set `System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin",path_of_ora)` I have tried for below approaches.

> Approach 1: Used broadcast variable to copy tns.ora file to all executors
>   sparkSession.sparkContext().broadcast("/tmp/conf/”,classTagTest)

Problem with this approach is `"/tmp/conf/”` is considered as string variable instead of path

> Approach 2: Used  --files parameter in spark submit command to pass tns.ora file and set --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Doracle.net.tns_admin=tnsnames.ora
>
> Approach 3: Used sparkSession.addFile(“tnsnames.ora”) set --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Doracle.net.tns_admin=tnsnames.ora

According to our analysis we found that system property is set when spark application is run with master as local[*] and mode client.

Even in client mode only local path is recognized and when we tried setting systemProperty with hdfs path it is not recognized.

But the requirement is to set the system property and run in cluster mode.

> spark-submit --class Demo1 --master local[*] --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 5g --executor-memory 10g --executor-cores 5 --num-executors 36 --jars ojdbc15-11.1.0.6.jar --files /tmp/tnsnames.ora --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Doracle.net.tns_admin=tnsnames.ora --driver-java-options -Doracle.net.tns_admin=tnsnames.ora test.jar tnsnames.ora

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
               // .setMaster("local[*]")
                .setAppName("Iden");

SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
        .config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();

String username = "etldevapp";
String password = "etldevappstg";
String thinConn = "jdbc:oracle:thin:" + username + "/" + password + "@xxxxxxx";

System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin","/tmp/");

try {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(thinConn, username, password);

    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from xxxx where rownum < 10");

    final ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    System.out.println(rs.getFetchSize());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception from try1 ");
}
```

User class threw exception: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: could not resolve the connect identifier "xxxxx"

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done.  I set it as a property in the Spark config file and then in code set it as a system property.  It's important that the property name start with "spark.", So something like this:

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin",conf.get("spark.your.property.name"));
```

Comment: SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().set("spark.oracle.tns_admin","/tmp").setAppName("Iden");
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin",sparkConf.get("spark.oracle.tns_admin"));

Problem is path "/tmp" is not recognized by other executors since it is local to driver.
If hdfs path is given,System.setProperty does not recognizes it.

Comment: does the property value need to be different on each executor??

Comment: The best thing to do is to make sure the tnsnames.ora file is in the same place on every executor and the driver.  That is, the path to the tnsnames.ora file is the same on every executor and the driver.

Comment: Property value is same for all executors

Comment: Path to tnsnames.ora is same in both driver and executor("/tmp/tnsnames.ora").I am able to read the content of the file and also printed the property set("oracle.net.tns_admin").All these are working fine but still getting exception "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Unknown host specified".Is there anything am missing?

Comment: Try using a newer driver.  Yours is a few releases old. https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

Comment: I have tried below approaches to fetch data:  

*Approach 1:     

    try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(thinConn, username, password);

            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from xxx where rownum < 10");

            final ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(rs.getFetchSize());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception from try1 ");
        }

Comment: Approach 2:
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());

            final Dataset<Row> ds = sparkSession.read()
                    .format("jdbc")
                    .option("url", thinConn)
                    .option("dbtable", "(SELECT * FROM " +  " xxxx "
                            + ")TBL")
                    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
                    .option("user", username)
                    .option("password", password)
                    .load();
                ds.show(10);
        }

Comment: With first approach result is fetched properly.Whereas in second approach getting "Unknown host exception".Requirement is to make both approaches work.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I don't know why the second version is not working.  It is still possible to create a Dataset from the first version

Comment: Make sure the tnsnames.ora file is in the same place on all executors and the driver.